# Format Comma10.2 or Dollar10.2 in SAS

Tags: sas, format

I have a question on format in SAS. Below is my code

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE OUT.FIN_POP_4a AS
SELECT sum(CORR_AM) as correction_am 
    FROM OUT.FIN_POP_4
;
QUIT;
```

correction_am is format numeric 8. How do I change this to Comma10.2 or Dollar10.2 in SAS in data step or proc sql code? I have tried various methods that did not work.

I have tried below code which worked but did not retain the two decimal places.

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE OUT.FIN_POP_4a AS
    SELECT sum(CORR_AM) as correction_am format comma10.
        FROM OUT.FIN_POP_4
;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need formatw.d but you have only formatw. w = width d = decimal. So you do not have any decimal part that is why you do not see decimals. See below example and try both of them. first one gives no decimals and second gives you decimal values.

```
 /*  no decimal part i.e comma10.*/
 PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE FIN_POP_4a 
  AS SELECT sum(weight) as correction_am format= comma10. 
  FROM sashelp.class ; QUIT;

  /* decimal part i.e comma10.2*/
 PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE FIN_POP_4a 
  AS SELECT sum(weight) as correction_am format= comma10.2 
  FROM sashelp.class ; QUIT;
```

Comment: You may need to increase length as well since if you have millions, billions, or trillions or dollars then there is an increase in length ie comma15.2 or comma20.2. Below recommendation:PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE FIN_POP_4a 
  AS SELECT sum(weight) as correction_am format= comma15.2 
  FROM sashelp.class ; QUIT;

Answer (score 0):

use format comma10.2 instead of format comma10. ...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to increase length as well since if you have millions, billions, or trillions or dollars then there is an increase in length ie comma15.2 or comma20.2. Below recommendation:

`PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE FIN_POP_4a AS SELECT sum(weight) as correction_am format= comma15.2 FROM sashelp.class ; QUIT;`